# JSON HTML OUTPUT

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to get JSON objects from 2 separate server sites but with my current code only the first object from the first site appears. I would like to know what is wrong with my current code and an explanation as to why only the first object appears considering i've tried to alter the variable names to prevent duplicates. I've also deleted the first xmlHttpRequest and functions which then allows the second xmlhttprequest to work.

Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>QUESTION 2</title>

    <script> 

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters/?n=0";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        function myFunction(responseText){
            var obj = JSON.parse(responseText);
            var out =""; 
            out =document.write("<h1>"+obj.data+"</h1>"); 
        }

        document.getElementById("Section1").innerHTML = out;

        var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url2 = "http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters/?n=1";

        xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp2.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp2.status == 200) {
                myFunction2(xmlhttp2.responseText);
            }
        }

        xmlhttp2.open("GET", url2, true);
        xmlhttp2.send();

        function myFunction2(responseText){
            var obj2 = JSON.parse(responseText);
            var out2 ="";
            out2=document.write("<h2>"+obj2.data+"</h2>"); 
        }

        document.getElementById("Section2").innerHTML = out2;

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id = "Section1"></section> 
        <br />
        <section id = "Section2"></section>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you are using document.write() which is replacing your page content. Use this :  function myFunction(responseText){
    var obj = JSON.parse(responseText);
var out ="";
out ="<h1>"+obj.data+"</h1>";
   document.getElementById("Section1").innerHTML = out;
}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `document.write` here:

```
function myFunction(responseText){
    var obj = JSON.parse(responseText);
    document.getElementById("Section1").innerHTML = "<h1>"+obj.data+"</h1>"; 
}
```

Same goes for your `myFunction2`. You can reduce your code as you have same functionality for different sections possibly using loop.

```js
var info = [{
  'id': 'Section1',
  'param': '0',
  'html': function(s) {
    return "<h1>" + s + "</h1>";
  }
}, {
  'id': 'Section2',
  'param': '1',
  'html': function(s) {
    return "<h2>" + s + "</h2>";
  }
}];

for (var i = 0, l = info.length; l > i; i++)
  ! function(o) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById(o.id).innerHTML = o.html(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data);
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters/?n=" + o.param, true);
    xhr.send();
  }(info[i]);
```

```html
<section id="Section1"></section>
<br/>
<section id="Section2"></section>
```

Comment: Thanks Arvin, your way is great help becuase i was constantly rewriting xmlhttprequests for several sections which was very time consuming